# Can I count on this general pattern executing correctly (similarly to C, C++ and probably any other language)?

Tags: solidity, compiler

Suppose I have something like this:

```
contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    MyTokenImpl private myTokenImpl;

    constructor(MyTokenImpl _myTokenImpl) public {
        myTokenImpl = _myTokenImpl;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
        let status = myTokenImpl.transfer(to, value);
        return status || super.transfer(to, value);
    }
}
```

In the expression `status || super.transfer(to, value)`, can I count on the right-hand side executing only if the left-hand side is `false`?

In every language that I know, this is indeed the case.

Can I count on the Solidity compiler to abide the same rules, i.e., jump out of the function without executing the right-hand side if and only if the left-hand side is `true`?

Is this specified anywhere in the official documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can count on it. Details: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#booleans

And you can also test this quite easily in Remix for example. Something like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0;
contract MyTest {

    function isFalse() internal pure returns (bool) {
        revert();
        return false;
    }

    function isTrue() internal pure returns (bool) {
        revert();
        return true;
    }

    function test() public pure {
        if (true || isFalse()) {
            // all ok
        }
        if (false && isTrue()) {
            revert();
        }
    }
}
```

Deploy the contract and call the `test` function. If it wouldn't work as you hope it does, it would revert. But it works just fine and doesn't revert so you know it works correctly.

Comment: Use this good effort to write a more clear and straightforward code. Do not recommend this attitude.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule every time the order of precedence of operators is a major issue in the program execution path, that is not the way to use them.

The order of precedence is there in order to solve unclear or unexplicit code and to fix the rules, but it is a recommended practice not to write code based on it.

In C/C++ that behavior happens because the short-circuit rule, that in this case omit to execute any further calculation after that any just executed results true. Very probably here in Solidity it shall be executed in the same way, even if nothing about this is specified as far as I know.

May be it cannot be assured when the next compiler shall be versioned. And from the logical point of view any optimizing permutations of operands is absolutely permitted (BECAUSE THE RESULT OF THE OR OPERATOR IS NOT AFFECTED BY PERMUTATIONS) And any optimizer is allowed to use that permutation if interesting or useful.

But ANYWAY this is a unnecessary unclear programming style in C/C++ as well.

The description of the code execution path should be explicit, not implicit.

Comment: I have to disagree. 1) This is quite clearly stated in the link I posted: "The operators || and && apply the common short-circuiting rules. This means that in the expression f(x) || g(y), if f(x) evaluates to true, g(y) will not be evaluated even if it may have side-effects". 2) it's quite common practice to use this rule in any programmin language and count on it that it works - at least in my experience

Comment: As I underlined, nothing prevent the compiler to permutate parameters in a logic evaluation if useful. The result is not affected. So you cannot be confident of that. On the contrary in an algebraic expression where the result should be eventually affected, the order is specified and mandatory.

Comment: leave this behavior to compiler optimizations and not to use to state program flow. Do you want to sell code where if someone, you or some other guy in the years, changes the way is written a logical expression, it ceases to work? Not to me.

Comment: yes, I am comfortable in selling applications which rely on this logic.

Comment: As I said, not to me! 

Comment: If short-circuiting wasn't guaranteed to work in C, then I might be in trouble... :-)

However, at least for C, such behaviour is defined in ISO/IEC 9899, sections 6.5.13 and section 6.5.14. This is the international standard which defines what all current and future implementation must adhere to. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf. Such expressions _must_ be evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: Short circuit is guaranteed in C. But it is useful in order to write the simpler expression first in the evaluation order to be more efficient in the mean use of the code. It is not a good practice to use it in order to implicitly have a path in the code. You can use a simple if to obtain the same and it is more readable and at last absolutely identical in bytecode, if not better when automatically optimized. Do not be of the church of “the more implicit the code is, the better is the code”. It is the enthusiastic newbie who loves implicit coding, not the pro. The pro want maintenable code.